# VS Code format HTML in JavaScript file (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a ReactJS project using VS Code with Prettier and ESLint installed, along with "AutoFormat on save" option. Every time I save my code, the block of codes turns from this:

```
  return ( <div style = { style }
      className = { className }>
      { children }
  </div>
  );
```

to this:

```
  return ( <
      div style = { style }
      className = { className } > { ' ' } { children } { ' ' } <
      /div>
  );
```

I always get the red error flag underlining the `div` tag: `JSX element 'div' has no corresponding closing tag.` However the compiler runs smoothly with no error or whatsoever.

It is not a systematically problem but it is indeed not pleasing to my eyes to see the way it is formatted and the error flag keep flashing all the time. Is there a solution to work around with this?

Comment: What happens if you wrap your div in a <React.Fragment>?

Comment: Try to add this rule [jsx-first-prop-new-line](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-first-prop-new-line.md) to your .eslintrc file

Comment: @TedFitzpatrick same problem

Comment: @matrixersp good suggestion but it's not related to the current issue. it helps to separate parameters within a tag to a new line but still shows red flag error